# Does my Macbook Pro support 5 GHz Wi-Fi?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, hardware

I have MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013). Does it support 5 GHz Wi-Fi?

I found the following details about Wi-Fi module there:

```
Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 
802.11 a/b/g/n
```

If 5 GHz are supported, then will it work with 2.4 GHz in parallel?

Comment: What do you mean by "in parallel"? Do you want to connect to two different WiFi networks at once (one on 2.4, one on 5)?

Comment: @patrix, no, I want to be connected to the same network (to the same router), but thru 2 channels at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your [MacBook Pro](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.4-15-early-2013-retina-display-specs.html) supports 2.4 GHz & 5 GHz but not simultaneously. All Macs manufactured since 2007 with integrated Wi-fi support 802.11 a/b/g/n and and some 2006 Macs support 802.11 a/b/g.

Only AirPort Base Station and Time Capsules released in March 2009 or later can operate simultaneously over both bands.

[Source](http://www.macworld.com/article/1140685/wifi_spectrumbands.html)

Comment: Thanks! How do you know that? And, I've changed Mhz to GHz ;).

Comment: Thanks again. What is about 5 GHz support? How do you know that for sure? Looks like I can check Broadcom's site, but what should I look for? What should be instead of `xx` in the chip model `BCM43xx`?

Comment: @LA_ I don't understand you first question in your comment? Did you mean 2.4 GHz?

Comment: Ah, sorry, looks like I've missed the first link. I.e. I was talking about 5 GHz, but didn't see the first link.